# Trying to run Raspberry-Pi image under QEMU, but VM memory is limited to 256MB

Tags: raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, qemu

I want to build a time consuming package (mediapipe) on my Raspberry-Pi buster image under QEMU. So far, I've gotten the image to load and run (including with network connectivity); however, I'm limited to 256MB of storage, which just isn't enough to do much - especially build a mediapipe. Can someone explain why Raspbian images running under QEMU seem to be limited to 256MB?
I've seen some posts about people running with 512MB and even one with 1GB, but they don't seem to be very successful. Can anyone explain the reason for the restriction, and a potential fix?

Comment: You don't specify the QEMU command line. Without that, it's impossible to say what the limitation is (though I have a guess...)

Comment: ok, here's my command line script to start the VM: #!/bin/bash
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M raspi3 \
    -append "rw earlyprintk=ttyAMA0,115200 loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=PARTUUID=9730496b-02 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait" \
    -cpu cortex-a53 \
    -dtb raspi32_qrpkmboot/dtbs/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb \
    -drive id=hd-root,file=2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img,format=raw \
    -show-cursor \
    -kernel ./raspi32_qrpkmboot/kernel8.img \
    -m 1024 \
    -serial stdio \
    -no-reboot

Comment: This VM booted, I have 1GB of memory, but I have no network.  I need a network connection and I've tried several alternatives: #    -net nic,macaddr=00:16:3e:00:00:01 -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no \
#    -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22 \
#    -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \    but neither of these will work,  I message on startup and no network.  I'm using a tap0/virbr0 combination which does work with other machine types.

Comment: You asked for 1GB of RAM, and it sounds like it worked. So the answer to your original question is "do what you did", it appears. Regarding networking: the raspi3 model has no support for plugging in virtio devices or PCI devices, because the real hardware has neither of those things. Plugging in an emulated USB network adaptor might work, or might not. For better networking support, you're better off using a different machine model, ie not trying to exactly emulate a raspberry pi.

Comment: Yes, I've gotten the ram issue resolved with this startup; but If I'm going to build software on this VM that'll run on the Raspberry Pi 3b, I need a way of getting packages and git-hub distro's onto the VM; and if I were to build using a different machine model wouldn't I have issues when I move it over to a real Raspberry Pi 3b - that's my concern now; thus the reason for needing a network connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that a lot of people claim to be running "raspberry pi emulation in QEMU" when they're actually just running Raspbian userspace on top of a kernel for a different machine emulation. So it's easy to be confused if you look at several different tutorials that are really describing entirely different emulation setups. Look for what machine type they pass QEMU.

The "versatilepb" machine type gets used in a lot of tutorials, especially older ones, because it has been in QEMU a long time and it is possible to get it to work with the 1176 CPU that the classic Raspberry Pi boards used. This specific machine has a 256MB maximum memory size, because the real hardware it's emulating has that restriction (it's imposed by the way the physical memory address space is designed). This machine type will never be able to support more RAM, so if you need more then you should ignore any tutorial or setup that uses it.

More recent versions of QEMU really do emulate the actual raspberry pi hardware; these are the raspi0, raspi1ap, raspi2b, raspi3ap, raspi3b machine types. These will have the same amount of RAM as the real raspi hardware they're emulating (either 512MB or 1GB). The downside of these board models is that some of the device emulation is lacking features -- so older QEMU will often not correctly boot a newer kernel, and sometimes devices you would like to use are not present. Also, because the raspi boards hang their ethernet device off the USB controller, the only way to get ethernet on these QEMU models would also be to use a USB ethernet device, eg with:

```
-device usb-net,netdev=eth0 -netdev user,id=eth0
```

This probably needs a recent QEMU version to get a working USB controller.

I don't know if there are any tutorials/recipes for running Raspbian on top of the QEMU "virt" board. If there are, this would probably be the best experience, because the virt board permits lots of memory, PCI devices, virtio devices, and is well maintained.

Comment: Unfortunately, I checked my qemu-system-arm version and it is 4.2.1 and I believe I need a higher version to support raspi3b; but, I can't find a 6.1 package for ubuntu 20.04.  I tried building from sources and the configure seems to have worked, but when I issue make from the build folder I get error and if I run make from the root folder (where Makefile is located) I get nothing to be done for 'all' - so I'm not having any luck getting 6.1.0 on my system.